# Aggregate numbers, some in ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, gaps-and-islands, natural-sort

I have a table `tab1` with the following values in my numeric column `c1`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
13
18
```

I want to return

```
1-5
6-10
13
18
```

The query below executes successfully in MySQL but not PostgreSQL:

```
select distinct
case
when c1 between 1 and 5 then '1-5'
when c1 between 6 and 9 then '6-10'
else c1
end as 'c1'
from tab1;
```

Comment: Tables don't have inputs. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I took the liberty to clarify as I understood the question. Please fix if I got it wrong.

Comment: Why would you want to split 1-10 into two different groups

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would use two levels of aggregation.  The first gets the ranges:

```
select min(c1), max(c1)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by c1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by c1 - seqnum;
```

The second then re-aggregates this:

```
select string_agg(range, ',' order by min_c1)
from (select (case when min(c1) <> max(c1) then min(c1) || '-' || max(c1) else min(c1)::text end) as range, min(c1) as min_c1
      from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by c1) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
      group by c1 - seqnum
     ) x
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=774d2eb268b5c98ff6c269606b0477ba) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that this logic works.

Comment: Both queries have errors, and (after fixing) neither produces what the OP asks.

Answer (score 1):

The same query works in Postgres after fixing syntax errors and with proper casting:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       CASE WHEN c1 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN '1-5'
            WHEN c1 BETWEEN 6 AND 9 THEN '6-10'
            ELSE c1::text END AS c1 
FROM   tab1;
```

The result has to be a string type - `text` is the preferred type in Postgres. But sorting by the string representation is no good for your numbers. So I suggest this alternative to allow proper sorting:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN c1 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN '1-5'
            WHEN c1 BETWEEN 6 AND 9 THEN '6-10'
            ELSE c1::text END AS new_c1   -- avoid duplicate of source name
FROM   tab1 t
GROUP  BY new_c1
ORDER  BY min(t.c1);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b505cbb0eae4d59dd24d7c4d2e8ab783)*